# Unexpected character for stdin

Tags: stdin, menhir

I'm tying `--interpret-error` and `interpret` of [menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/manual.html).

For [this sample](https://gitlab.inria.fr/fpottier/menhir/-/tree/master/demos/calc-syntax-errors), I typed `menhir --interpret-error parser.mly` or `menhir --interpret parser.mly` in the command line, then for any expression I entered, it returned

```
File "(stdin)", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: unexpected character.
(I believe I am reading a sentence, but may be off.)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: can you give an expression failing ?

Comment: In this chapter an example is shown: http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec55